# Don't scale image when smaller than container

Tags: css

Currently I have the following rule

```
 img{
     height: 100%;
     width:100%;
 }
```

This works fine in most of the cases.

Is it possible to display the image at it actual size when -

```
    image width < container width
```

Please note that image width is unknown.

UPDATE: CONTAINER WIDTH IS ALSO UNKNOWN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `object-fit` and `object-position` property work for me. So my new rule with this property -

```
img{
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
    object-fit: scale-down;
    object-position: 0 0; /*top left position (optional)*/
}
```

Comment: the `max-width`-solution  has been my to go to solution as well, but this solution is most explicit solution actually referring to how an image can be scaled. I think the max-width solution just happens to work most of the time, but today I ran into a situation where it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is. Set the `max-width` to `100%` of the container so that when the container shrinks beyond the intrinsic (original) image size, the image also shrinks (as how it behaves in your *current rule*). This way, the image isn't forced to set its width to 100% of its container; it is allowed to maintain its intrinsic size (i.e. it only needs to shrink its size when the container is smaller than its intrinsic size because its width is limited to a maximum of 100% of the container).

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 40px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container-two {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<p>Image within container. Container is 500px wide, but image doesn't scale; it still maintains its intrinsic (original) width</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/white-transparent-leaf-on-mirror-260nw-1029171697.jpg">
</div>

<p>Image within container. Container is 300px wide (smaller than the original image width, which is 381px), but image still shrinks to fit inside the container while displaying fully</p>
<div class="container-two">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/white-transparent-leaf-on-mirror-260nw-1029171697.jpg">
</div>

<p>Image not within container. Original image size (381px for the width)</p>
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/white-transparent-leaf-on-mirror-260nw-1029171697.jpg">
```

Comment: I am looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: @s.k.paul Have you looked at the code carefully? **It is** a pure CSS solution. The js is to show the original width. The only content in that JS is `console.log`.

Comment: @s.k.paul I've deleted the JS section to log the actual image width.

Comment: Container width is unknown too. See the question update.

Comment: @s.k.paul The solution still works. My answer is only showing you examples with the container width known; to show that the solution indeed works.